# Getting Black Screen with navigationController?.pushViewController (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having problems programmatically sending a user from one view controller to another. I am posting the code associated with he flow below. In addition to letting me know what the correct code is (which I would appreciate) I'd also be interested if the logic/design itself seems OK.

I am controlling my UI programmatically. Accordingly, in my app delegate didfinnishlaunchingwithoptions I have

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
FIRApp.configure()
window?.rootViewController =  SigninController()
```

When the user opens the app, they are redirected to the SigninController.
Then, inside of SigninController, I am handling all of the social authentication stuff against Firebase. I have a listener in my code to confirm that the user is (or is not) authenticated and sends him along:

```
  let provider: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIFacebookAuth()]
        FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.providers = provider

        // listen for changes in the authorization state
        _authHandle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth: FIRAuth, user: FIRUser?) in
            // check if there is a current user
            if let activeUser = user {

                // check if the current app user is the current FIRUser
                if self.user != activeUser {
                    self.user = activeUser
                    self.signedInStatus(isSignedIn: true)
                    print("user session is active, redirecting...")
                    let nextViewController = CustomTabBarController()
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

                }
            } else {
                // user must sign in
                self.signedInStatus(isSignedIn: false)
                self.loginSession()
            }

        }

    }
```

In the above code, if the user is confirmed as signed in, then I use the below code to send them along. This is where I am having the problem. Right now I just see a black screen but no error message.

```
let nextViewController = CustomTabBarController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

And here is the code for the CUstomTabBarController class.

```
class CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let home = createNavController(imageName: "gen-home", rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
    let loc = createNavController(imageName: "loc-map-route", rootViewController: LocController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
    let stats = createNavController(imageName: "pre-bar-chart", rootViewController: StatsController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
    let profile = createNavController(imageName: "account", rootViewController: ProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))

    viewControllers = [home, loc, stats, profile]

    }

    private func createNavController(imageName: String, rootViewController: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController
    {
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
            navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        return navController
    }

}
```

I am sure I am overlooking something silly, but sometimes it takes another pair of eyes to point it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating all view controllers programmatically? You are not referencing any storyboard or XIB file in your code.

Comment: Hi there. Yes, that is correct. No storyboard or XIB file at all.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.navigationController` is not `nil`? It seems that `SigninController` is not embedded in one. If it's `nil`, try replacing `SigninController()` with `UINavigationController(rootViewController: SigninController())`

Comment: hmm... that may be correct. i am setting up all of my controllers inside of CUstomTabBarController. SigninController is not part of my core view controllers so it isn't in that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

there is no `navigationController`.

In your `AppDelegate` you need to do this:

```
let rootViewController = SigninController()
let navController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
FIRApp.configure()
self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

It's better to assign `rootViewController` to the `window` before making it visible. Otherwise there may be screen blinks.

Comment: Thanks Max. I will try that now. I am wondering how it will play with CustomTabBarController, where I am setting up UINavigationController.

Comment: @CodeSherpa, welcome. There shouldn't be a problem. You will just have two `UINavigationController`s. Basically, you don't need to care about them, only in special cases.

Comment: Thanks Max. I can see the view now, thanks! However, there seems to be a related problem, if you don't mind. What is happening now is the black view is still there but only for a split second, then it redirects to the appropriate controller (in this case, homeviewcontroller inside of customtabbarcontroller). However, there is a back button and the user can go back to the black screen. I want to skip the black screen altogether and have my homeviewcontroller be the parent view. Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed self.present(nextViewController, animated: false, completion: nil). Thanks again!

Comment: @CodeSherpa, you found the answer yourself, so no need to thank me :)